# Why are there now blank entry folders in my image assets folder?

Tags: assets

There are folders in my images asset folder `craft/public_html/images/` named for individual entries (posts).  But, the folders are empty.  This is something new.  Only recent posts are represented.  The actual images for these and all posts are still there, the settings have not changed and everything seems okay. And, it appears I can delete one of these empty folders without negatively impacting the actual post.

Is this a quirk or associated with a recent update and therefore has some purpose?  Should I delete them or leave them?

Thanks

Comment: You haven't by any chance added an image transform?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you or someone else made a subfolder in your upload folder. You can do this through Craft itself. This creates a folder you which might be happening in your case. Try adding a new one and see if it happens again. Go to assets and right click a folder to make a sub folder.